# How do I get Date but Manually enter time to then calculate countdown expiry?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am I want to select a and back date a time, add 8 hours to the timer and start a countdown based on the calculated remaining time. Basic Webpage in HTML/CSS/JS to monitor curing time of a product. I need to set the timer of 8 hours after I have mixed the resin which can be a random start time.

I can hard code the deadline time from the newDate and getTime but I'm struggling to understand how to manually enter the time and to calculate then deadline time. The actual calculation is easy enough for variable t to then start the countdown, it is the backdated start time then adding 8 hours that stumps me.

```
<script>
var deadline = new Date("March 25, 2021 12:34:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var t = deadline - now;
var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    if (t < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Rotate";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: To create a Date 8 elapsed hours from now: `new Date(Date.now() + 2.88e7)`, i.e. add 8 hours worth of milliseconds to the current time.

Comment: Thanks RobG appreciate the input :)